# Excel-VBA if statement runs without checking and validating the right values

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have little snippet of code which is supposed to extract the value of a few cells if their headers correspond to certain categories. The variables are private. However, the code runs and selects the first if statement and sets it to true EVEN IF the header is not "HFO 360" or "HFO 180" or "HFO 60".

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub_Consumption()    
Dim HFOConsumed, HFORemaining, MDOConsumed, MDORemaining As Double

With Activesheet

HFOConsumed = 0
HFORemaining = 0
MDOConsumed = 0
MDORemaining = 0

If .Cells("M44") = "HFO 380" Or .Cells("M44") = "HFO 180" Or .Cells("M44") = "HFO 60" Then
    HFOConsumed = .Range("M45").Value
    HFORemaining = .Range("M46").Value
ElseIf .Cells("N44") = "HFO 380" Or .Cells("N44") = "HFO 180" Or .Cells("N44") = "HFO 60" Then
    HFOConsumed = .Range("N45").Value
    HFORemaining = .Range("N46").Value
ElseIf .Cells("O44") = "HFO 380" Or .Cells("O44") = "HFO 180" Or .Cells("O44") = "HFO 60" Then
    HFOConsumed = .Range("O45").Value
    HFORemaining = .Range("O46").Value
Else
    HFOConsumed = 0
    HFORemaining = 0
End If

.Range("P45") = HFOConsumed
.Range("P46") = HFORemaining


If .Cells("M44") = "MDO" Or .Cells("M44") = "MDO M/E" Then
    MDOConsumed = .Range("M45").Value
    MDORemaining = .Range("M46").Value
ElseIf .Cells("M44") = "MDO" Or .Cells("M44") = "MDO M/E" Then
    MDOConsumed = .Range("N45").Value
    MDORemaining = .Range("N46").Value
ElseIf .Cells("M44") = "MDO" Or .Cells("M44") = "MDO M/E" Then
    MDOConsumed = .Range("O45").Value
    MDORemaining = .Range("O46").Value
Else
    MDOConsumed = 0
    MDORemaining = 0
End If

.Range("Q45") = MDOConsumed
.Range("Q46") = MDORemaining

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, I'm afraid. This:

```
If .Range("M44") And .Range("N44") And .Range("O44") = "MDO" Or "MDO M/E" Then
```

has to be broken out specifically - something like:

```
If (.Range("M44").Value = "MDO" Or .Range("M44").Value = "MDO M/E") And (.Range("N44").Value = "MDO" Or .Range("N44").Value = "MDO M/E") And (.Range("O44").Value = "MDO" Or .Range("O44").Value = "MDO M/E") Then
```

depending on whether all three cells have to contain the same one of those two values, or they just have to all contain one of the two values.

Also, note that it's `WorksheetFunction.Sum` and not `Worksheet.Function.Sum` so your `.Function.Sum` won't work.

Comment: Well, in each instance the cells have to contain one of those values.
@A.S.H Pray tell, no need to be snide about it.

Comment: But do all three have to contain the **same** one, or is it ok if say M44 and N44 have "MDO" and O44 has "MDO M/E"?

Comment: The cells must contain any of the stipulated arguments, your example is exactly what I want. Thank you for the `WorksheetFunction.Sum` I have updated that part.

Comment: @BOB I did not mean to offend at all, but to notify Rory so probably he could complete his answer. Anyway, what puzzled me most in your OP was the sentence *"So, the cells that are expected to contain the sum are simply blank"*. In fact, your code should not compile in the first place, and that left me wondering with the "too many" feeling :)

Comment: @A.S.H Funnily enough, it did compile. However, it did not do anything that I could discern.

Comment: @Rory I have integrated the new If formulation you suggested. However, the values returned remain blank. I also put a watch on both `MDOConsumed` and `HFOConsumed` they both indicate that they are Empty, so the code isn't even running throw otherwise it would be `"0"`...?

Comment: @Rory I have updated the question to reflect the current situation and results I am getting.

Comment: Syntax still wrong. `If .Cells("M44") = "HFO 380" Or "HFO 180" Or "HFO 60" Then` must be `If .Cells("M44") = "HFO 380" Or .Cells("M44") = "HFO 180" Or .Cells("M44") = "HFO 60" Then` and so on.

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestion the code still executes and returns the wrong values. It seems as if the if statement doesn't even check the real value of `cells("M44")`. Because it always returns that segment as `True`.

Comment: I ended changing for a `select case` function, thanks all the same!